# FireBase + React: TypeError: user.getToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

Here is the code **signInWithEmailAndPassword** works perfectly but when I try to acquire a token the error is always thrown `TypeError: user.getToken is not a function`.

```js
import app from "./base.js";

app.auth()
   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then(function (user) {
      user.getToken().then(function (token) {
        localForage.setItem("token", token); // store the token
        console.log("pusing forward");
        history.push("/");
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("err: " + error);
     });
```

base.js

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
   databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
   projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
   storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
});

export default app;
```

Comments welcome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API documentation for [signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) `user` is a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object.  It doesn't have a `getToken` method.  Perhaps you want to use its `user` property to get a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object, which has a [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) method.

```
    user.user.getIdToken().then(token => { ... })
```

Here is a peak at the object `user1` returned after calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` 
[image]